# Return Postgres timestamps in 'x days ago' format

Tags: postgresql

It's pretty common in web applications these days to display timestamps in time intervals relative to whatever the time is now, like `5 days ago`, `3 hours ago`, `34 minutes ago`, or `just now` if < a few seconds.

I tried finding a postgres function online that would convert timestamps to this kind of format but surprisingly I couldn't really find any. Does anyone know of any good functions written for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtracting a timestamp from a timestamp yields an `interval` which contains exactly the information you want.

E.g.

```
select timestamp '2020-04-18 21:30:15 - timestamp '2020-04-13 14:10:00')
```

return

```
0 years 0 mons 5 days 7 hours 20 mins 15.0 secs
```

You can use `to_char()` to get the output you want:

```
select to_char(timestamp '2020-04-18 21:30:15' - timestamp '2020-04-13 14:10:00', 'dd "days" ago, hh24 "hours" ago, mi "minutes" ago')
```

If you want something that is more dynamic you can use this:

```
with t(diff) as (
  select timestamp '2020-04-18 21:30:15' - timestamp '2020-04-13 14:10:00'
)
select concat_ws(' and ', 
                  nullif(extract(year from diff), 0)||' years',
                  nullif(extract(month from diff), 0)||' months',
                  nullif(extract(day from diff), 0)||' days',
                  nullif(extract(minute from diff), 0)||' minutes')||' ago')
from t
```

which returns:

```
5 days and 20 minutes ago
```

Comment: Very cool, that's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately PostgreSQL doesn't support `DATEDIFF`. Otherwise you'd be able to use this to capture `year(s)`, `month(s)`, `day(s)`, `hour(s)`, `minute(s) ago` + `just now` using this code:

```
-- SQL Server --

SELECT
  CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(yy, now(), time_field)) > 1 THEN CONCAT((DATEDIFF(yy, now(), time_field), ' years ago'))
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(yy, now(), time_field)) = 1 THEN CONCAT((DATEDIFF(yy, now(), time_field), ' year ago'))
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(mm, now(), time_field)) > 1 THEN CONCAT((DATEDIFF(mm, now(), time_field), ' months ago'))
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(mm, now(), time_field)) = 1 THEN CONCAT((DATEDIFF(mm, now(), time_field), ' month ago'))
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(dd, now(), time_field)) > 1 THEN CONCAT((DATEDIFF(dd, now(), time_field), ' days ago'))
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(dd, now(), time_field)) = 1 THEN CONCAT((DATEDIFF(dd, now(), time_field), ' day ago'))
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(hh, now(), time_field)) > 1 THEN CONCAT((DATEDIFF(hh, now(), time_field), ' hours ago'))
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(hh, now(), time_field)) = 1 THEN CONCAT((DATEDIFF(hh, now(), time_field), ' hour ago'))
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(mi, now(), time_field)) > 1 THEN CONCAT((DATEDIFF(mi, now(), time_field), ' minutes ago'))
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(mi, now(), time_field)) = 1 THEN CONCAT((DATEDIFF(mi, now(), time_field), ' minute ago'))
    ELSE 'just now'
    END AS time_ago
FROM your_table
```

---

Because you're using PostgreSQL, however, you'll have to use some code that doesn't look as pretty or as concise:

```
-- PostgreSQL --

SELECT
  CASE
-- year(s)
    WHEN (DATE_PART('year', now()) - DATE_PART('year', time_field)) > 1
      THEN CONCAT((DATE_PART('year', now()) - DATE_PART('year', time_field)), ' years ago')
    WHEN (DATE_PART('year', now()) - DATE_PART('year', time_field)) = 1
      THEN CONCAT((DATE_PART('year', now()) - DATE_PART('year', time_field)), ' year ago')      
-- month(s)
    WHEN (((DATE_PART('year', now()) - DATE_PART('year', time_field)) * 12) + (DATE_PART('month', now(), time_field))) > 1
      THEN CONCAT((((DATE_PART('year', now()) - DATE_PART('year', time_field)) * 12) + (DATE_PART('month', now(), time_field))) ' months ago')
    WHEN (((DATE_PART('year', now()) - DATE_PART('year', time_field)) * 12) + (DATE_PART('month', now(), time_field))) = 1
      THEN CONCAT((((DATE_PART('year', now()) - DATE_PART('year', time_field)) * 12) + (DATE_PART('month', now(), time_field))) ' month ago')
-- day(s)
    WHEN DATE_PART('day', now() - time_field) > 1
      THEN CONCAT(DATE_PART('day', now() - time_field), ' days ago')
    WHEN DATE_PART('day', now() - time_field) = 1
      THEN CONCAT(DATE_PART('day', now() - time_field), ' day ago')
-- hour(s)
    WHEN ((DATE_PART('day', now() - time_field) * 24) + (DATE_PART('hour', now() - time_field))) > 1
      THEN CONCAT((DATE_PART('day', now() - time_field) * 24) + (DATE_PART('hour', now() - time_field))), ' hours ago')
    WHEN ((DATE_PART('day', now() - time_field) * 24) + (DATE_PART('hour', now() - time_field))) = 1
      THEN CONCAT((DATE_PART('day', now() - time_field) * 24) + (DATE_PART('hour', now() - time_field))), ' hour ago')
-- minute(s)
    WHEN ((DATE_PART('day', now() - time_field) * 24) + ((DATE_PART('hour', now() - time_field)) * 60) + (DATE_PART('minute', now() - time_field))) > 1
      THEN CONCAT(((DATE_PART('day', now() - time_field) * 24) + ((DATE_PART('hour', now() - time_field)) * 60) + (DATE_PART('minute', now() - time_field))), ' minutes ago')
    WHEN ((DATE_PART('day', now() - time_field) * 24) + ((DATE_PART('hour', now() - time_field)) * 60) + (DATE_PART('minute', now() - time_field))) = 1
      THEN CONCAT(((DATE_PART('day', now() - time_field) * 24) + ((DATE_PART('hour', now() - time_field)) * 60) + (DATE_PART('minute', now() - time_field))), ' minute ago')
-- seconds        
ELSE 'just now'
    END AS time_ago
FROM your_table
```

Note you'll need duplicate lines of code to differentiate between `1` and `>1` for each time part. For example, you'll want `1 day ago` instead of `1 days ago`.

Here is some reference documentation for you:

[Date/Time Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-datetime.html)

[The CASE expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE)

Answer (score -3):

This would be efficient if done at the client's end. The DB server will end up doing a lot of processing in memory for this.

Comment: Doing it on the client is fine, but that's not one the questions about.